change policy to access a script
By mistake, I requested to block access to a script to run neo4j (local server).Since then, I have the issue below:

Translated in English:
neo4j : The file "D:\Haku-Sci\neo4j-community-5.23.0\bin\neo4j.ps1" cannot be
loaded because the operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by Group Policy.
At line:1 Characters:1
+ neo4j console
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : Security Error: (:) [], PSSecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I tried to remove group access (in system32) via the commands:
RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers".
RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy".
then
gpupdate /force
I tried to change the policies to unrestricted for all: Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
Of course, I restarted my computer.
No change at all, the program is still blocked.
I could activate gpedit.msc, but I don't know where to go then (Or if it is relevant).

"By mistake, I requested to block access" - so go back and tell whoever's in charge of SRP to revert the change.

I expressed it wrongly: I myself made the wrong choice, when my terminal asked me if I wanted to blcok this script!
